# How to extract more than one patterns from a string using Python Regular Expressions?

Tags: python, regex

`https://epolicy.companyname.co.in/PRODUCTNAME/UI/PremiumCalculation.aspx?utm_source=rtb&utm_medium=display&utm_campaign=dbmew-Category-pros&dclid=CO2g3u7Gy98CFUOgaAodUv4E0w`

I have millions of such URLs and I want to extract two things from this.

1. PRODUCTNAME: always preceded by `https://epolicy.companyname.co.in`
2. *.aspx: Page accessed

I tried the following regular expression

`re.findall('([a-zA-Z]+\.aspx | https://epolicy\.companyname\.co\.in/(.*?)/UI)', URL)`

and a few variants of it. But it didn't work. What it the correct way to do this?

Comment: Did you try running them separately? Note the spaces on both sides of `|` are meaningful. Also, see https://regex101.com/r/N0MJaX/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

**Code :**

```
import re
url = "https://epolicy.companyname.co.in/PRODUCTNAME/UI/PremiumCalculation.aspx?utm_source=rtb&utm_medium=display&utm_campaign=dbmew-Category-pros&dclid=CO2g3u7Gy98CFUOgaAodUv4E0w"
print(re.findall('https://[^/]*/(.*)/UI/(.*).aspx', url))
```

**Output :**

```
[('PRODUCTNAME', 'PremiumCalculation')]
```

Answer (score -1):

Regex doesn't seem to be the right thing to use here at all. Rather, parse the URL, split the path, and get the first and last elements.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from pathlib import PurePath

components = urlparse(url)
path = PurePath(url.path)
product_name = path.parts[1]
page = path.stem
```